# Python script running in linux

Tags: python

I am having trouble trying to get this script to work. When I debug this code it will not read into the class or functions. The code will not execute properly. Has anyone know the problem here, Thanks

```
#!/home/build/test/Python-2.6.4

import os, subprocess

class mks_function:

 sandbox="new_sandbox"

 def mks_create_sandbox():  
  try:  
   retcode=call("si createsandbox" + "--no --hostname=bel --port=70 --user=user --password=1234 --populate --project=e:/project.pj --lineTerminator=lf new_sandbox", shell=True)  
   if retcode < 0:  
    print >>sys.stderr, "Child was terminated by signal", -retcode  
   else:  
    print >>sys.stderr, "Child returned", retcode  
 except OSError, e:  
    print >>sys.stderr, "Execution failed:", e  
    print "sandbox retVal="+retcode  
    print "Creating a new sandbox called "+sandbox+" "  
###############################################################
```

Comment: Please use the formatting features of SO to format you code so that it matches what you have in your file. It's impossible to see where the problem might be. Also, maybe post the error messages you received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things to check your code

- `call` should be `subprocess.call`
- better use full path when you call for example, `/usr/bin/si createsandbox`, you can check with `which si` in shell
- instead of concatenating the commands `"si createsandbox" + "--no ..."`, please use list `["/usr/bin/si","createsandbox --no ..."]`
- you didn't import `sys`, but using it
- `sandbox` should be `self.sandbox` and `def mks_create_sandbox():` should be `def mks_create_sandbox(self):`
- Use an IDE for example [Ulipad](http://code.google.com/p/ulipad/).

Answer (score 1):

Try put as the first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

If you really need specific version of Python, setup your environment before running.

Possible problems:

- your code is never executed (it's like you define the class only). Use it in the file (names are misleading):

  `if __name__ == '__main__':
      myObject = mks_function()`
- show us how are you executing the code? Have you changed the permissions to be able to run the script?

  `chmod +x filename.py`
- or are you trying to start it as:

  `python filename.py`

Comment: setting up environment variables is **MUCH** easier in the long run.